# Matrices - order of operations

Tags: matrices

If I have matrices $A, B,$ and $C$ and then I have to solve this:
$X = 3A − 2BC$
what is the order of operations for the $2BC$ part? Do I multiply matrices $B$ and $C$ first and then I multiply the result by $2$? Or do I multiply matrix $B$ by $2$ first and then multiply the two matrices? Thank you kindly.

Comment: It doesn’t matter (you could think of multiplying by $2$ as multiplying by twice the identity matrix, and matrix multiplication is associative)

Comment: Indeed, $2(BC)=(2B)C$, where $2B=\operatorname{diag}(2,2\ldots, 2)B$.

Comment: Thank you all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any matrices $X$ and $Y$ that have compatible sizes (the number of columns of $X$ equals to that of the rows of $Y$), and any scalar $\lambda$, we have
$$
\lambda(XY)=(\lambda X)Y.
$$

(You can even do $X(\lambda Y)$ and get the same result.)

This is why we usually omit the paratheses and write $\lambda XY$.